# How can I set Windows 8 sharing to enable writing to root?

Tags: windows-8, file-sharing, file-permissions

I have a file-server running on Windows 8. The data drives in the server are shared to admin users with full control permissions on the whole drive. However, for some reason, I am unable to write or delete files in the root of the shared drives when accessing the drive mapped as a network drive on a Windows 7 work station.

I can remote in with the same credentials and make any changes I want. I can also create folders in the mapped drives, and read/write/delete inside any folder on the drive.

What changes should I look at making to enable writing and deleting in the root from a mapped drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default if the remote computer is running in UAC mode the remote computer provides a filtered token for the logon session with standard user privileges instead of full administrator privileges. To allow full administrator privileges add the following registry value:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Policies\System
DWORD LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy = 1
```

Note: This issue does NOT normally affect the Administrator account, only standard user accounts which are subsequently added to the Administrators group.

Alternatively you could grant specific write access for that user to the root.

Comment: That appears to exactly be the issue. I hadn't realized but the changes made when remoting in did require me to grant admin UAC before they were allowed. I also found that I could add permissions to the "Authenticated Users" group to solve this, but obviously that opens up the drive to non-Admin users (which, in this case, is desired, since it is a drive for shared data storage).